# How to make or get tile sized Windows Phone vector icons

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am familiar with the standard application icon images that come with the Windows Phone sdk, but I would like to use some of these images as demonstrated on the standard start screen, with the 173x173 dimensions for the application tiles. I've tried resizing these, but they are so blurry they aren't worth using. Is there a place to download the same (or similiar) images that come with SDK except in a larger size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [Metro Studio by Syncfusion](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/metrostudio). I use it in all my applications and its `free`.

Answer (score 3):

Also have a look at the [Icons8 icon pack](http://icons8.com/), they only ask for a link to their site or $199 without a link

Comment: Some icons are available now as large PNG and SVG only for a link https://icons8.com/free-icons